# Trying to Quicksort a linked list in python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, linked-list, quicksort

my professor has asked me to perform a Quicksort for a linked list. It is getting quite confusing as all the recursion and links are still very new to me. The issue seems to be with something unintentionally being assigned as None
This is my code so far:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, d, n):
        self.data = d
        self.next = n


class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.length = 0

    def append(self, d):
        if self.head == None:      
            self.head = Node(d,None) 
        else:
            ptr = self.head
            while ptr.next != None:
                ptr = ptr.next
            ptr.next = Node(d,None)
        self.length += 1

    def merge(self,other):
        ptr = self.head
        while ptr.next != None:
            ptr = ptr.next
        ptr.next = other.head

    def removeVal(self, d):
        if self.head == None:
            return
        if self.head.data == d:
            self.head = self.head.next
            self.length -= 1
        else:
            ptr = self.head 
            while ptr.next != None:
                if ptr.next.data == d:
                    ptr.next = ptr.next.next
                    self.length -= 1
                    break
                ptr = ptr.next  

    def sort(self):
        if self.head!=None:
            pivot=self.head.data
            self.removeVal(pivot)
            smaller=LinkedList()
            other=LinkedList()
            ptr=self.head
            while ptr.next!=None:
                ptr=ptr.next
                if ptr.data<pivot:
                    smaller.append(ptr.data)
                else:
                    other.append(ptr.data)
            smaller.sort()
            other.sort()
            self=smaller
            self.append(pivot)
            self.merge(other)


ls = LinkedList()
ls.append(0)
ls.append(1)
ls.append(3)
ls.sort()
```

Running this gives the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 71, in <module>
    ls.sort()
  File "main.py", line 58, in sort
    other.sort()
  File "main.py", line 51, in sort
    while ptr.next!=None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: You do not check whether any elements end up in smaller or other. Each may be empty if the head is larger/smaller than all other elements.

Comment: The questions code is similar in concept to quicksort, but it's not quicksort, which would involve swapping of nodes. Make sure that this approach is acceptable to the professor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sort() function fails because `ptr` can be None when you get to your while loop.
This isn't obvious at first because of your check at the beginning

```
if self.head != None
```

But the call to `self.removeVal(pivot)` will set your head pointer to None if the list has only 1 entry. 
Note that this will ALWAYS happen during your quicksort eventually, because you're breaking down your list recursively. Eventually it MUST be a 1-element list and therefore fail.

When this happens you get the stacktrace you posted where it says:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

To fix this you can rewrite your while loop to look at the `ptr` directly and not at `ptr.next`

```
         while ptr is not None:
                if ptr.data<pivot:
                    smaller.append(ptr.data)
                else:
                    other.append(ptr.data)
                ptr=ptr.next
```

Another issue I found was with your assignment:

```
self=smaller
```

It may be legal python code but I find it very dangerous. I changed it to

```
self.head = smaller.head
```

Otherwise your example dropped one element from the list (though I didn't track down why exactly)
Note this doesn't really update your length attribute, but I didn't see why it is needed, it's not used anywhere.

One more note on efficiency: you are doing a lot of appends in your algorithm and they are VERY expensive with lists, i.e. the way you have implemented them. That's probably not the point of your exercise here. But when you are appending by iterating over all existing elements you are killing the efficiency of quicksort. Adding an element costs you O(n) and therefore splitting the list into your smaller and other list costs you already O(n^2).

For (linked) lists merge sort is a much better sorting algorithm that also runs O(n*log(n)) just like quicksort.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete code

```
#finding the pivot elemet
def partition(itemlist,low,high):
pivot=itemlist[high]
i=low-1
for j in range(low,high):
    if itemlist[j]<pivot:
        i=i+1;
        itemlist[i],itemlist[j]=itemlist[j],itemlist[i]
itemlist[i+1],itemlist[high]=itemlist[high],itemlist[i+1]
return i+1
# generating the partition
def sort(itemlist,low,high):
    if low < high:
        partitonIndex=partition(itemlist,low,high)
        sort(itemlist,low,partitonIndex-1)
        sort(itemlist,partitonIndex+1,high)
# array to be sort
itemlist=[5,3,6,2,7,1,2,9]
print(itemlist);
sort(itemlist,0,len(itemlist)-1)
print(itemlist);
```

Output

```
[5, 3, 6, 2, 7, 1, 2, 9]
[1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Read your error codes carefully. It says

```
File "main.py", line 51, in sort
while ptr.next!=None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Thats a pretty good indicator of what and where the issue is. You are accessing a null node from line 51. Change `While ptr.next !=None` to `While ptr != None` and the error goes away. You need to figure out why through testing though.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, make sure that the approach shown in the question will be acceptable as as a quicksort. You might consider creating 3 lists, nodes < pivot, nodes == pivot, nodes > pivot, and only using recursion on the 2 list of nodes != pivot. Adding a tail reference to list will speed up append operations. Example code where the quicksort relinks nodes to rearrange them instead of constantly allocating nodes.

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next=None

class Linkedlist(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.length = 0

    def push_back(self, data):
        self.length += 1
        new = Node(data)
        if(self.tail is None):
            self.head = self.tail = new
        else:
            self.tail.next = new
            self.tail = new

    def pop_front(self):
        if(self.head is None):
            return self.head
        self.length -= 1
        data = self.head.data
        self.head = self.head.next
        return data

    def show(self, head, tail):
        arr = []
        if(head is None):
            print(arr)
            return
        while(True):
            if(head.data is not None):
                arr.append(head.data)
            if(head is tail):
                break
            head = head.next
        print(arr)

    def quicksort(self,head,tail):
        if(head is tail):               # if single node return
            return head,tail
                                        # using 3 dummy nodes for 3 lists
        hlt = Node(None)                # head, tail < pivot list
        tlt = hlt
        heq = Node(None)                # head, tail = pivot list
        teq = heq
        hgt = Node(None)                # head, tail > pivot list
        tgt = hgt
        pivot = head
        curr  = head
        end   = tail.next
        while(curr is not end):
            if(curr.data < pivot.data):
                tlt.next = curr
                tlt = curr
            elif(curr.data == pivot.data):
                teq.next = curr
                teq = curr
            else:
                tgt.next = curr
                tgt = curr
            curr = curr.next
        heq = heq.next                  # at least 1 node (should release node)
        if(hlt is tlt):                 # if none < pivot
            hlt = heq                   #  (should release dummy node)
            tlt = heq
        else:                           # else recurse on list < pivot
            hlt = hlt.next              #  (should release dummy node)
            hlt,tlt = self.quicksort(hlt,tlt)
            tlt.next = heq
        if(hgt is tgt):                 # if none > pivot
            hgt = teq                   #  (should release dummy node)
            tgt = teq
        else:                           # else recurse on list > pivot
            hgt = hgt.next              #  (should release dummy node)
            hgt,tgt = self.quicksort(hgt,tgt)
            teq.next = hgt
        return(hlt,tgt)

    def sort(self):
        if (self.head == None):         # if empty list return
            return
        self.head,self.tail = self.quicksort(self.head,self.tail)
        self.tail.next = None
        return

lists=Linkedlist()
lists.push_back(27)
lists.push_back(35)
lists.push_back(23)
lists.push_back(22)
lists.push_back(38)
lists.push_back(26)
lists.push_back(31)
lists.push_back(24)
lists.push_back(37)
lists.push_back(25)
lists.push_back(33)
lists.push_back(32)
lists.push_back(28)
lists.push_back(36)
lists.push_back(21)
lists.push_back(34)
lists.sort()
arr = []
while(True):
    data = lists.pop_front()
    if(data is None):
        break
    arr.append(data)
print(arr)
```